# Explanation of what is happening with REPL

Tags: scala

I've been learning/experimenting with Scala in the REPL.
By the way, and as a side note, I'm quite impressed so far. I'm finding the language beautiful.

The following happened and need an explanation of what is going on.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

At the REPL entered:

```
def withMarks(mark: String)(body:  => Unit){
  println(mark + " Init")
  body
  println(mark + " End")
}
val a = "Testing clojure with paremeter by name as control structure"
withMarks("***"){
  println(a)
  println("more expressions")
}
```

Everything worked as expected.

Than happened what I consider weird, out of ignorance I suspect. I entered some more stuff:

```
class FileAsIterable{
  def iterator = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/Users/MacBookProRetina/Google Drive/NewControl.scala").getLines()
}

val newIterator = new FileAsIterable with Iterable[String]
```

When evaluating the last line the REPL prints:

```
newIterator: FileAsIterable with Iterable[String] = (def withMarks(mark: String)(body:  => Unit){,   println(mark + " Init"),   body,   println(mark + " End"), }, val a = "Hola Mundo", withMarks("***"){,   println(a), })
```

I keep getting the same result even after restarting the terminal in the Mac, and running the scala REPL at different directory locations.

Don't know how the newIterator val got connected to the the withMarks def.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I was just confused by the contents of the file